# Php sender with js

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I never worked with php before, but I've use jquery and js. I am making a web page, and I found this php function that I want to use, to send email messages from my page:

```
<?php
    $to      = 'the name';
    $subject = 'the subject';
    $message = 'the message';
    $headers = 'From: Some one?' . "\r\n" .
               'Reply-To: no-reply@address.com' . "\r\n" .
               'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();

    mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
?>
```

How can I launch this function to send 1 email from my site, when I press a button on the screen. Maybe through js, jquery anyways..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the php file is named `mailer.php` use ajax with jQuery like

```
$.ajax({
      url: "mailer.php"
    });
```

This will send a request to `mailer.php` in your server.

Regarding the button, you can do

```
<button id="MailIt">Mail</button>
```

Then put the ajax code in the click handler like

```
$('#MailIt').click(function(){
     ajax code here
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can pass variables to php by adding to the url. us can change the window.location in Jscript.

say you want to send the "to" and "subject" through.
you'd need to change the url from www.example.com/mailer.php to

> 'url': 'www.example.com/mailer.php?to=user@example.com&subject=hello'

then you need to change the php to accept these variables.
u can check for them first :

```
if(isset($_GET['to'])
    $to = $_GET['to'];
if(isset($_GET['subject'])
    $subject = $_GET['subject'];
//...
//etc
```

Answer (score 0):

You must to send HTTP request to URL of your PHP code.